# Number of synchronous concurrent requests for long-running requests that last longer than 5 seconds for each organization

Tags: governorlimits

The title is one of the limits of salesforce.

**Link** : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_apex_governor_limits.htm

but I'm not understanding in a full way the meaning of this limit and I'm not finding enougth use-cases explanation on the web...

anyone can give me some examples to understand this limit:

- For example what mean exactly "concurrent requests",  mean any server operation type ?
- In the 5 seconds what is considered ? Apex code after the request, Trigger operations? Query time execution, Callout transaction time?
- How Salesforce understand that one transaction is going to take more than 5 seconds?
- What time of best practises must be considered to avoid this limit?

Thnks, 
Klodjan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Designing Force.com Applications That Avoid Hitting Concurrent Request Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/force-com-concurrent-request-limits.html)

Answer (score 6):

The two main examples, and I'm sure there are more that I am missing, of a concurrent request include:

- A trigger exercising apex not operating in @future context
- A Visualforce page and corresponding controller/extension code not operating in @future context

At it simplest terms, a concurrent request is a single transaction that must execute in real time (i.e. is not queued) and consumes server processor cycles to do so.

The 5 seconds is from the start of the order of execution to the end, as defined in the Triggers and Order of Execution document: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

If you've ever looked at your debug log for a trigger firing, you would see that Salesforce has the exact start time of your transaction, as well as the finish time, that is how they record the overall transaction time.